# MySQL compatibility or similarity ranking queries

Tags: mysql, sum, diff

G'day, I'm trying to develop a way to query compatibility or similarity between values and failing. It's not a highest or lowest AVG rating but rather smallest difference between values over a number or rows. So if structure is something like the following where RANK is the "rating" by the USER.

```
USER  ITEM   RANK
A      x      5
B      x      6
C      x      2
A      y      2
B      y      3
C      y      8
A      z      7
B      z      4
C      z      4
```

At the end I'd like to be able to sort across the data like:

User A vs User B have avg rating difference of 3

User A vs User C have avg rating difference of 4

User B vs User C have avg rating difference of 5

My only thought so far is to build a temp table (huge) with every permutation:

```
col1  col2  dif   item
A      B      1      x
A      C      3      x
```

etc...
And then SUM with a GROUP. But that still doesn't deal properly with occasions where User A and C match closer on some items and have greater diff on other items to outweigh the initial closeness. Any direction anyone can give?

Thanks!

This is a mysql 5.5 db so I'm missing any CTE or the like on query structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could be using a self join

```
select a.user, b.user, abs(a.rank - b.rank) diff_rank, a.item
from my_table a
inner join my_table b on a.item  = b.item and a.user <> b.user
order by item, diff_rank asc
```

for avoid  duplicated  value  you can use distinct

```
select distinct a.user, b.user, abs(a.rank - b.rank) diff_rank, a.item
from my_table a
inner join my_table b on a.item  = b.item and a.user <> b.user
order by item, diff_rank asc
```

and for obtain the users with the lowest diff firts you can change the order by

```
select distinct a.user, b.user, abs(a.rank - b.rank) diff_rank, a.item
from my_table a
inner join my_table b on a.item  = b.item and a.user <> b.user
order by diff_rank asc
```

Comment: Thanks! that does a good job in gathering the results for each item rank even though it doubles the results. Finding the pair of users with the lowest combined diff_rank across multiple items is still eluding me. I suppose I can script arrays for each user pair and total the diff_rank outside of mysql? Also can filter the a.user-b.user  b.user-a.user duplicates. Though I could get it all done in mysql.